# Encoding a string the CSS way with python

Tags: python, css, string

Is there a function or package in python that I can use to encode a string according to make sure it can be used as a [CSS string](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/syndata.html#strings)? It would need to escape all single and double quotes and backslashes, and replace newlines with `\A`.

For instance:

```
This is "it", isn't\
it?
```

should be converted to

```
This is \"it\", isn't\\\A it?
```

Non-ASCII characters can be left untouched, if they are printed as utf-8.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at the rules, all that needs to be escaped are quotes (single and double) and newlines. The standard doesn't mention it, but this presumably must extend to the backslash character too (confirmed by checking [MDN on the `<string>` data type](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/string)).

A regular expression can do that:

```
re.sub(r'''['"\n\\]''', lambda m: '\\{:X} '.format(ord(m.group())), inputstring)
```

This escapes the 4 characters to hexadecimal escapes that are unambigous; the [`{escape}` macro uses the space after the escape to delineate the escape from any content following it](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/syndata.html#tokenization). This is the *most pragmatic* option; it produces a valid CSS string value.

Demo:

```
>>> import re
>>> inputstring = '''This is "it", isn't\nit?'''
>>> re.sub(r'''['"\n\\]''', lambda m: '\\{:X} '.format(ord(m.group())), inputstring)
'This is \\22 it\\22 , isn\\27 t\\A it?'
>>> print(re.sub(r'''['"\n\\]''', lambda m: '\\{:X} '.format(ord(m.group())), inputstring))
This is \22 it\22 , isn\27 t\A it?
```

Comment: Thank, I'll try that, but note that: (1) Hexadecimal escapes are not needed, except for newlines. (2) A space must be included after the escape, otherwise the following character might be interpreted as part of the hexadecimal number (though it doesn't occur in this example).

Comment: @Jellby: Hexadecimal escapes are *permitted*, and using them makes this **much simpler**. It also means you don't have to detect if you need to use `'` single or `"` double quotes.

Comment: @Jellby: ah, the space after the escape isn't actually part of the content. Will adjust.